# Microsoft Graph API mail message encryption

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I couldnt find information related to Microsoft Graph API Mail messages (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mail_api_overview) retrieval of encrypted mail messages in office 365. 
What happens if mail has been encrypted, will I still be able to retrieve it? what metadata and data can be exposed?

Answer (score 3):

> What happens if mail has been encrypted,
>   will I still be able to retrieve it? what metadata and data can be
>   exposed

Yes, you still can retrieve the message list, but you cannot get the actual message body by Graph API. Mail **Body**/**BodyPreview** will show as below:

> This message is protected with Microsoft Information Protection. You
>   can open it using Microsoft Outlook, available for iOS, Android,
>   Windows, and Mac OS. Get Outlook for your device here:
>   http://aka.ms/protectedmessage. Microsoft Information Protection a

My test request string:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=startswith(subject,'Data Protected mail test')&top=1
```

Response data(metadata for your reference):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('my user id')/messages",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=startswith(subject%2c%27Data+Protected+mail+test%27)&top=1&$skip=1",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADI9sWjzaI4R7XL22NiFR43AACWTT+Z\"",
            "id": "AAMkADQ5OWMzMGEwLTg4ZjktNDk1Ny05NzFmLWRh……bPeZSPaAAF6dOzdAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2016-11-03T05:23:25Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-09-04T11:19:40Z",
            "changeKey": "CQAAABYAAADI9sWjzaI4R7XL22NiFR43AACWTT+Z",
            "categories": [],
            "receivedDateTime": "2016-11-03T05:23:25Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2016-11-03T05:20:36Z",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "internetMessageId": "<……@…….prod.outlook.com>",
            "subject": "Data Protected mail test ",
            "bodyPreview": "This message is protected with Microsoft Information Protection. You can open it using Microsoft Outlook, available for iOS, Android, Windows, and Mac OS. Get Outlook for your device here: http://aka.ms/protectedmessage. Microsoft Information Protection a",
            "importance": "normal",
            "parentFolderId": "……=",
            "conversationId": "……=",
            "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
            "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
            "isRead": false,
            "isDraft": false,
            "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID= ……&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
            "inferenceClassification": "focused",
            "body": {
                "contentType": "text",
                "content": "This message is protected with Microsoft Information Protection. You can open it using Microsoft Outlook, available for iOS, Android, Windows, and Mac OS. Get Outlook for your device here: http://aka.ms/protectedmessage. Microsoft Information Protection allows you to ensure your emails can’t be copied or forwarded without your permission. Learn more at http://microsoft.com/rms."
            },
            "sender": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Test admin",
                    "address": "testadmin@microsoft.com"
                }
            },
            "from": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Test admin",
                    "address": "testadmin@onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            },
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Test admin",
                    "address": "testadmin@onmicrosoft.com"
                } ,
                 "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Test admin",
                    "address": "testadmin@onmicrosoft.com"
                }   
            ],
            "ccRecipients": [],
            "bccRecipients": [],
            "replyTo": [],
            "flag": {
                "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```